# Select the rows that do not exists in other df

Tags: r, sqldf, not-exists

I have a df with trip id, stop id, timestamp and speed.

```
   trip_id stop_id speed timestamp
 1       1       1     5         1
 2       1       1     0         2
 3       1       1     0         3
 4       1       1     5         4
 5       1       2     2       101
 6       1       2     2       102
 7       1       2     2       103
 8       1       2     2       104
 9       1       3     4       201
10       1       3     0       202
```

I have saved the first and last rows where the speed is zero for the groups where trip_id and stop_id are the same.

```
df_departure_z <- sqldf("SELECT trip_id, stop_id, MAX(timestamp) FROM df WHERE speed = 0 GROUP BY trip_id,stop_id")
df_arrival_z <- sqldf("SELECT trip_id, stop_id, MIN(timestamp) FROM df WHERE speed = 0 GROUP BY trip_id,stop_id")
```

Which gave the results:

df_departure_z:

```
trip_id stop_id MAX(timestamp)
1       1       1              3
2       1       3            203
```

df_arrival_z:

```
trip_id stop_id MIN(timestamp)
1       1       1              2
2       1       3            202
```

My problem: There is one stop (stop 2) where the speed is never zero and therefore I want to find a way to save one timestamp for the stops where the speed is never zero. I have tried this:

```
df_arr_dep <- sqldf("SELECT trip_id, stop_id, MIN(timestamp) FROM df GROUP BY trip_id, stop_id EXCEPT SELECT trip_id, stop_id FROM df_arrival_z ")
```

But it gives me an error since I am trying to save three columns based on the values in two columns in the other df. Basically, I want to search through my df again and find those combinations of trip_id and stop_id that are not in the df_departure_z or df_arrival_z. If I try with SELECT * I get all the rows which are not saved, which is also wrong.

Comment: Try with `anti_join` from `dplyr`

Comment: is `df_departure_z` correct? I only see one 0 speed entry for `trip_id` 2 and `stop_id` 3, with a `timestamp` of 202.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use other libraries besides `sqldf`? I think the following accomplishes what you're looking for using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(trip_id, stop_id) %>%
  filter(speed == 0 | sum(speed == 0) == 0) %>%
  summarize(min_time = min(timestamp),
            max_time = if_else(sum(speed == 0) == 0,
                               NA_real_,
                               max(timestamp)))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   trip_id [?]
  trip_id stop_id min_time max_time
    <int>   <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1       1       1        2        3
2       1       2      101       NA
3       1       3      202      202
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(trip_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                      stop_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
                      speed = c(5L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 0L),
                      timestamp = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 201L, 202L)),
                 .Names = c("trip_id", "stop_id", "speed", "timestamp"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -10L),
                 class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly for each trip and stop you want the row having maximum timestamp for which the speed is zero or if there is no such row then the maximum timestamp row for the rows having non-0 speed in that group.  Further down we make the alternate assumption that in the case of no 0 speed rows in a group just use NA.  After that we discuss the EXCEPT query in the question.

In the first case above, group by trip, stop and speed == 0. This will give 2 rows per trip and stop if there are both 0 and non-0 speeds and will give 1 row trip trip and stop if there are only non-0 speeds.  Within each group we take the row for speed == 0 is largest.  Since TRUE > FALSE then if there are two rows it will take the row for which speed is 0 and otherwise it will take the single non-zero speed row.

```
sqldf("SELECT trip_id, stop_id, timestamp, MAX(speed0) speed0
  FROM 
    (SELECT trip_id, stop_id, MAX(timestamp) timestamp, speed == 0 speed0
    FROM df 
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 4)
  GROUP BY 1, 2")
```

giving:

```
  trip_id stop_id timestamp speed0
1       1       1         3      1
2       1       2       104      0
3       1       3       202      1
```

The 1 in row 1 for speed0 means that a speed == 0 row was found for that group so it used the max timestamp of just the speed == 0 rows for that group. Similarly in row 2 the 0 for speed0 means that no speed == 0 row was found for that group so it used the max timestamp for the non-0 rows in that group.

If you don't want the 4th column just add [-4] after the ending ) .

### Alternate interpretation

If what you wanted was NA in those rows for whicih there is no speed == 0 then just replace the first line in the sql above as shown here:

```
sqldf("SELECT trip_id, stop_id, NULLIF(MAX(speed0) * timestamp, 0) timestamp
  FROM 
    (SELECT trip_id, stop_id, MAX(timestamp) timestamp, speed == 0 speed0
    FROM df 
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 4)
  GROUP BY 1, 2")
```

giving:

```
  trip_id stop_id timestamp
1       1       1         3
2       1       2        NA
3       1       3       202
```

Another way to do that is with a left join giving the same result:

```
sqldf("WITH a(trip_id, stop_id) AS (
         SELECT distinct trip_id, stop_id
         FROM df),
      b(trip_id, stop_id, timestamp) AS (
         SELECT trip_id, stop_id, MAX(timestamp) timestamp
         FROM df
         WHERE speed == 0
         GROUP BY 1, 2)
      SELECT *
      FROM a LEFT JOIN b
      USING (trip_id, stop_id)")
```

### EXCEPT vs. NOT EXISTS

Regarding the last line of code in the question involving EXCEPT it would be done using the following correlated subquery shown involving NOT EXISTS like this:

```
sqldf("SELECT a.trip_id, a.stop_id, MIN(a.timestamp) timestamp
  FROM df a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS  (
    SELECT *
    FROM df b
    WHERE speed == 0 AND a.trip_id = b.trip_id AND a.stop_id = b.stop_id)
  GROUP by 1, 2")
```

giving:

```
  trip_id stop_id timestamp
1       1       2       101
```

### Note

We assume this input shown in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
   trip_id stop_id speed timestamp
 1       1       1     5         1
 2       1       1     0         2
 3       1       1     0         3
 4       1       1     5         4
 5       1       2     2       101
 6       1       2     2       102
 7       1       2     2       103
 8       1       2     2       104
 9       1       3     4       201
10       1       3     0       202"
df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```